# Ionic $http call for iOS doesn't work

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app that does a simple $http.get() call to a webservice. The app works fine when I run it in Android, works fine when I run it via `ionic serve` and I see the data returned. However when I run the iOS emulator no data is returned by the app.

Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable App Transport Security in your apps **.plist** file. It's enabled by default in iOS 9 and only allows **https** calls.

To disable it, add the following in your .plist file (taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mlynch/284699d676fe9ed0abfa)):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

For more information, read [this post](http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/) on the Ionic blog.

Comment: That was it. Thanks @liima - appreciate it!